# How to convert .pep file extension to .fasta in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have 536 .pep files. I need to convert all files to .fasta extension. Please let me know how to convert in python

Comment: Please edit and add arepresentative example of the "pep file".

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your code.